# Why Boolean type cannot do bitwise operation in swift

Tags: swift, boolean, bitwise-operators

As the title, why bitwise operator cannot apply to Boolean type in swift, which kind of swift data type can work with bitwise operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integers are the ones with bits, so all integer types can do *bitwise* operations, as you could readily have seen for yourself merely by consulting the header; for example, here's bitwise-and:

```
public func &(lhs: Int, rhs: Int) -> Int
public func &(lhs: UInt, rhs: UInt) -> UInt
public func &(lhs: Int64, rhs: Int64) -> Int64
public func &(lhs: UInt64, rhs: UInt64) -> UInt64
public func &(lhs: Int32, rhs: Int32) -> Int32
public func &(lhs: UInt32, rhs: UInt32) -> UInt32
public func &(lhs: Int16, rhs: Int16) -> Int16
public func &(lhs: UInt16, rhs: UInt16) -> UInt16
public func &(lhs: Int8, rhs: Int8) -> Int8
public func &(lhs: UInt8, rhs: UInt8) -> UInt8
```

Bool is not a numeric type in Swift; Booleans are about logic, so they do *logical* operations. For example, here's logical-and:

```
public func &&<T : BooleanType, U : BooleanType>(lhs: T, @autoclosure rhs: () throws -> U) rethrows -> Bool
```